# The connection between the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle and wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I have recently read Something Deeply Hidden by Sean Carroll, and in the book, he tries to sum up how the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle can be found from just the way wavefunctions work, but I couldn't understand it. How are the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle and Wavefunctions connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because:

$$ p = -i\hbar\frac{d}{dx} $$

You can't have a constant derivative and a fixed $x$ (e.g. $\delta(x)$). As $\psi(x)$ becomes more localized, the standard deviation of $d\psi(x)/dx $ grows, and vice versa.

Comment: This applies only to the uncertainty principle for position and momentum.